# Styling Windows Phone 8 Toast Messages

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, toast

Are there any ways to style the Windows Phone 8 Toast messages at all?

I have an application that I am receiving and displaying messages fine after registering the Toast template (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx), however if the pushed message is too long it seems to just get cut off on the edge of the screen. I can't seem to find a mechanism where I can manage this (like make the text wrap, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot style the toast messages.

Comment: Is there a recommended max length for most devices?

Comment: The font used is a proportional one, so the visible length would depend on the content.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Not entirely sure why this question merited a downvote.